# Textbox lost focus while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I am working on web application and ran into issue where textbox looses focus while typing.

To be specific, let me explain how did it happens:

1. User Clicks on a textbox and start typing.
2. As soon as user types first letter in textbox, it looses focus.
3. To continue typing user has to click once again in textbox.

[image]

**NOTE:  Textbox is editable dropdown.**

Below is the code used for dropdown.

```
<input type="text" id="placeDeathState" name="placeDeathState" size="3" maxlength="25" 
    value="" style="vertical-align:top; margin:2px 0px 0px 0px; border:0px;" 
    onfocus="focusAutoSelect(document.getElementById('placeDeathState'), 2, '', '', '');" 
    onblur="this.autoSelect.hideComboList();">
```

**UPDATE-1:**
code for function focusAutoSelect()

```
function focusAutoSelect(obj, col, tgts, cols, scripts) {
    if (!obj.autoSelect)
        obj.autoSelect = new AutoSelectCombo(obj.id, col, tgts, cols, scripts);
}
```

**UPDATE-2:**

AutoSelectCombo object:

Here is what it does:

This is the AutoSelectCombo object. Although it began as a 
linear autoselect, it is now a select by filtration. Anything
typed into this box will be used to filter the option list to 
only the items containing the text that was typed.

```
function AutoSelectCombo(id, col, tgts, cols, scrs) {
    this.editFocused= false;
    this.selFocused = false;
    this.timer      = null;
    this.column     = col;
    this.quicksel   = false;
    this.quickstr   = "";
    this.targets    = new Array();
    this.columns    = new Array();

    this.scripts    = scrs.split("#");
    this.gotChar    = false;
    this.ascDiv     = document.getElementById(id+"div");
    this.ascText    = document.getElementById(id);
    this.ascImage   = document.getElementById(id+"btn");
    this.ascEditBtn = document.getElementById(id+"edit");
    this.ascSDiv    = document.getElementById(id+"combo");
    this.ascSelect  = document.getElementById(id+"select");
    this.ascFrm     = document.getElementById(id+"ifrm");
    this.options    = new Array();

    this.lastLen    = this.ascText.value.length;
    this.maxItems   = 10;
    this.blurClosed = false;
    this.selIndex=0;

    if ((tgts!=null) && (tgts!="")) {
        this.targets    = tgts.split("|");
        this.columns    = cols.split("|");
    }

    if (this.ascText.readOnly == true)
        this.quicksel = true;

    for (; this.selIndex<this.ascSelect.length; this.selIndex++)
        if (this.ascSelect.options[this.selIndex].value == this.ascSelect.value)
            break;

    if (this.selIndex >= this.ascSelect.length)
        this.selIndex = -1;

    if (this.ascDiv)
        this.ascDiv.autoSelect = this;
    if (this.ascText)
        this.ascText.autoSelect = this;
    if (this.ascImage)
        this.ascImage.autoSelect = this;
    if (this.ascEditBtn)
        this.ascEditBtn.autoSelect = this;
    if (this.ascSDiv)
        this.ascSDiv.autoSelect = this;
    if (this.ascSelect)
        this.ascSelect.autoSelect = this;

    this.ascText.oldOnFocus = this.ascText.onfocus;
    this.ascText.onfocus = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.editFocused = true;

        if (this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnFocus)
            this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnFocus.call(this.autoSelect.ascText);
    }

    this.ascText.oldOnBlur = this.ascText.onblur;
    this.ascText.onblur = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.editFocused = false;
        this.autoSelect.handleBlur(evt);

        if (this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnBlur)
            this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnBlur.call(this.autoSelect.ascText);
    }

    this.ascText.oldOnKeyDown = this.ascText.onkeydown;
    this.ascText.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.handleComboKeyDown(evt);

        if (this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyDown)
            this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyDown.call(this.autoSelect.ascText);
    }

    this.ascText.oldOnKeyPress = this.ascText.onkeypress;
    this.ascText.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.handleComboKeyPress(evt);

        if (this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyPress)
            this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyPress.call(this.autoSelect.ascText);
    }

    this.ascText.oldOnKeyUp = this.ascText.onkeyup;
    this.ascText.onkeyup = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) {
            evt = window.event;
        }

        this.autoSelect.handleComboKeyUp(evt);

        if (this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyUp) {
            this.autoSelect.ascText.oldOnKeyUp.call(this.autoSelect.ascText);
        }
    }

    this.ascImage.oldOnClick = this.ascImage.onclick;
    this.ascImage.onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) {
            evt = window.event;
        }

        this.autoSelect.editFocused = true;
        this.autoSelect.toggleComboList();
        this.autoSelect.blurClosed = false;

        //if (this.autoSelect.ascImage.oldOnClick)
        //  this.autoSelect.ascImage.oldOnClick.call(this.autoSelect.ascImage);
    }

    this.ascSelect.oldOnKeyPress = this.ascSelect.onkeypress;
    this.ascSelect.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        var keyCode = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which ? evt.which : evt.charCode;
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            this.autoSelect.hideComboList();
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.ascSelect.oldOnChange = this.ascSelect.onchange;
    this.ascSelect.onchange = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.setComboValue();
//      this.autoSelect.hideComboList();

        //if (this.autoSelect.ascSelect.oldOnChange)
        //  this.autoSelect.ascSelect.oldOnChange.call(this.autoSelect.ascSelect);
    }

    this.ascSelect.oldOnClick = this.ascSelect.onclick;
    this.ascSelect.onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) {
            evt = window.event;
        }

        this.autoSelect.setComboValue();
        //this.autoSelect.ascText.focus();
        //this.autoSelect.hideComboList();

        for (i=1; i<this.autoSelect.scripts.length; (i=i+1)) {
            eval(this.autoSelect.scripts[i]);
        }

    }

    this.ascSelect.oldOnFocus = this.ascSelect.onfocus;
    this.ascSelect.onfocus = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.selFocused = true;
    }

    this.ascSelect.oldOnBlur = this.ascText.onblur;
    this.ascSelect.onblur = function(evt) {
        if (!evt) 
            evt = window.event;

        this.autoSelect.selFocused = false;
        this.autoSelect.hideComboList();

    }

    this.duplicateElements();

}
```

I am not getting how to investigate further and what goes wrong.

Comment: check your focusAutoSelect function

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @Proleev I have updated question, please have a look. This is entire code I have. The HTML code I took from browser console.

Comment: What this object makes? `AutoSelectCombo`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Please see my UPDATE-2

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on the blur event, see who triggers it. My bet is somewhere inside `new AutoSelectCombo`. Are there other event handlers registered for this input?

Comment: @geert3 I added breakpoint and could see 

`AutoSelectCombo.prototype.hideComboList = function() {
 var b = true;
 if (this.timer != null) {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  this.timer = null;
  
  b = this.blurClosed;
  this.blurClosed = false;
 }
 
 if (b) {
  this.ascSDiv.style.display = "none";
  this.ascSDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  //this.ascSDiv.style.zIndex = "199";
  this.lastLen = this.ascText.value.length;
  
  iFrm = this.ascFrm;
  
  if (document.getElementById) {
   iFrm.style.display = "none";
  }
  
 }
}`

This function gets called on the blur event

Comment: What you should look for when you hit the breakpoint is the call stack. This will (hopefully, not certainly) hint towards the source of the blur event.

Comment: @geert3 What do you mean by call stack. sorry for question but I am newbie in front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem,

The problem was with the function `showComboList`, after a match is found, Combo list is shown and is focused, as a result focus is lost from the input element.

Inside the function `AutoSelectCombo.prototype.showComboList = function(){`,
remove/comment the line that says `fs.focus()`.

& you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate :)